# Fastest way to a scan portion of the file system in Java

Tags: java, performance, filesystems

I need to scan a deeply nested portion of the file system containing thousands of files on each start of the application. I need name, size and change date in order to find new and changed files. Using Java there are different ways to do this, e.g. using `File`, using `Files`, using `walk`. What is the fastest way?

Comment: You could try them all and see which one is faster.

Comment: Is it a single directory or a nested (with what hierarchy) directories?

Comment: deeply nested portion of the file system containing thousands of files. (clarified question)